# How to sort an array and find the two highest peaks after using find_peaks from Scipy

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am struggling find_peaks a little...

Im applying a cubic spline to some data, from which I want to extract some peaks.  However, the data may have several peaks, while I only want the two largest.  I can find the peaks

```
peak_data = signal.find_peaks(spline, height=0.3, distance=50)
```

I can use this to get the x and y values at the index points within peak_data

```
peak_vals = spline[peak_data[0]]
time_vals = xnew[peak_data[0]] # xnew being thee splined x-axis
```

I thought I could order the `peak_vals` and keep the first two values (ie highest and second highest peaks) and then use that to get the time from xnew which coincides with those values. However, I am unable to use `.sort` which returns

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

or `sorted()` which returns

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'dict'
```

I think this is because it is indexing from a Numpy array (the spline data) and therefore creates another numpy array which then does not work either of the sort commands.

The best I can manage is to iterate through to a new list and then grab the first two values from that:

```
peak_val1=[]

peak_vals = spline[peak_data[0]]
    for i in peak_val_d:
        peak_val1.append(i)
peak_val1.sort(reverse=True)
peak_val2 = peak_val1[0:2]
```

This works but seems a tremendously long winded way to do this given that I still need to index the time values. I'm sure that there must be a faster (simpler) way?

Added Note:  I realise that find_peaks returns an index list, but it actually seems to contain both index's and max values in and array-dictionary?? (sorry Im very new to python and curly braces means dictionary but it doesn't look like a simple dict).  Anyway...  `print(peak_data)` returns both the index positions and their values.

```
(array([ 40, 145, 240, 446]), {'peak_heights': array([0.34588031, 0.43761898, 0.45778744, 0.74167977])})
```

Is there a way to directly access these data perhaps?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just posting this incase anyone else has similar trouble and to remind myself to read the docs carefully in future!

Assuming there are no additional arguments,  `find_peaks()` returns a tuple containing and array of the indexes of the peak values, and a dictionary of the actual peak values. Once I realised this it's pretty simple to perform sequence unpacking to generate a separate array and dictionary.  So if I began with

```
peak_data = signal.find_peaks(spline, height=0.3, distance=50)
```

all I needed to do was to unpack to two variables

```
peak_index, dict_vals = peak_data
```

Now I have the index and the values in the order they were identified.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
peak_indices, peak_dict = signal.find_peaks(spline, height=0.3, distance=50)
```

This returns the indices of all the peaks in the array, as well as a dictionary of information about the peaks, such as their heights, prominences, etc. To get the heights of the peaks you can access the dictionary like this:

```
peak_heights = peak_dict['peak_heights']
```

Then to find the indices of the highest and second-highest peak you can do:

```
highest_peak_index = peak_indices[np.argmax(peak_heights)]
second_highest_peak_index = peak_indices[np.argpartition(peak_heights,-2)[-2]]
```

Hope this helps someone somewhere:))

Comment: If you don't actually want to specify a certain `height`, but still want to access the height of found peaks, use `height=(None, None)`. Otherwise peak_dict will have no 'peak_heights' key.